# Cannot login into Cirros instance

Tags: instance, openstack

I am a newbie in Openstack. I have deployed Openstack using packstack on CentOS7 VM, all-in-one installation.

I have created internal network, external network (with CentOS gateway setting), created router connecting internal and external network. Also created Security groups giving ping and ssh access.

I have created a Cirros instance and connected to internal network. Assigned floating IP as well. When I tried to ping / ssh newly created instance from CentOS7 server, Ping Fails.

My gateway IP is not pingable from Cirros instance. Did I miss anything?

Comment: From inside the virtual machine Are you able to ping the floating IP gateway ? And also check whether IP is assigned for interfaces in virtual machine

Comment: Hi Mahesh - In external network gateway configurations I have given my virtual machine gateway IP, so from my VM gateway IP is pingable. Also when I checked virtual machine interfaces I don't see IP assigned to the interface. here is what I see  _ qvo1e8d519d-e0: flags=4419<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,MULTICAST>  mtu 1450
        inet6 fe80::d0bb:e0ff:fe80:ee81  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether d2:bb:e0:80:ee:81  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 144  bytes 14237 (13.9 KiB)
        TX packets 102  bytes 12456 (12.1 KiB) _

Answer (score 2):

You need to check a few things step by step:

1. You need to ensure that Your VM has been assigned IP on the interface. If IP is not assigned on the interface of your VM then you wouldn't be able to ping your VM.
2. Check if Ingress ICMP access is enabled in security group attached to the Cirros VM. Disable any firewall at Controller itself if enabled.
3. Check if External Network was created correctly as suggested by below link:
   https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/111383/can-not-ping-router-or-vms-on-private-network-that-i-created-in-openstack/
4. If still no luck then enter into the router namespace and check if you are able to see your ping packets till router interface:

eg:

[root@controller ~]# ip netns

```
 qrouter-ed88c298-9b70-4d69-aa6b-8751aaf2f2d4
```

[root@controller ~]# ip netns exec qrouter-ed88c298-9b70-4d69-aa6b-8751aaf2f2d4 bash

[root@controller ~]# ip a

1: lo:  mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1

```
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

23: **qg-530165fa-f6**:  mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1000

```
link/ether fa:16:3e:03:dd:8e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 172.19.80.19/24 brd 172.19.80.255 scope global qg-530165fa-f6
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fe03:dd8e/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

26: qr-ed726183-0d:  mtu 1450 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1000

```
link/ether fa:16:3e:0f:b7:ca brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 11.11.123.1/24 brd 11.11.123.255 scope global qr-ed726183-0d
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fe0f:b7ca/64 scope link
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

[root@controller ~]# tcpdump -i **qg-530165fa-f6**

5. You need to dive a little bit deeper if you still can't ping your VM. You can refer the following link which is detailed and descriptive.
   https://dischord.org/2015/03/09/troubleshooting-openstack-neutron-networking-part-one/